# A bit complex Vbs

Tags: vbscript

I have to create a vscript a bit complex, at least for me.. If anyone could help, I will thank you so much! :D

these are the tasks that the script needs to take care of:

```
*-run this cmd file located on "C:\Program Files\Paradigm\Paradigm-15\Services\bin\cli\PG_epos_user_list.cmd" -pns_host localhost
```

that cmd generates a list of users so, from this cmd's output, I need to check if current logged accountname are listed there (check if it matches)*

*-If it is not listed, run another cmd -> 
    "C:\Program Files\Paradigm\Paradigm-15\Services\bin\cli\PG_epos_user_create.cmd" -pns_host localhost -epos_user  -member_list*

but in this case, we have to input logged userid on each "" on that commandline.

then, compare the content on a ini file, stored on a shared disk, with the values on 2 files located on `C:\ProgramData\Paradigm\Paradigm-15\Applications\config\env\common\`

```
1_epos_license_location  & 1_epos_license_location.tcl
```

Get the license value from section "[License]" `value Stratimagic=**licensevalue**`
and be sure that matches with the license info on both `1_epos_license_location & 1_epos_license_location.tcl.`

If it not matches, update both files.
Also, check if W disk is mapped, if not, advise with a msgbox

Thanks guys!,I have this so far (working), all the italic part, is working.

```
dim objshell

    sub runCommand(strCommand)
       Dim oShell
       Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
       oShell.Run strCommand, 0, TRUE
    end sub

Private Function File2Output(tempfile)
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile(tempfile, 1)
        out = ""
        out = txtStream.ReadAll
        txtStream.Close
        fso.DeleteFile tempfile
        File2Output = out
End Function


call runCommand("%COMSPEC% /c ""C:\Program Files\Paradigm\Paradigm-15\Services\bin\cli\PG_epos_user_list.cmd"" -pns_host localhost > c:\log.txt")

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")

user = objNetwork

cmdOut = File2Output("c:\log.txt")
'WScript.echo cmdout
'WScript.echo user
'WScript.echo InStr(cmdOut, user)
if InStr(cmdOut, user) > 0 Then
                WScript.echo "Found"
Else
                WScript.echo "Not Found"
End if
```

Thanks in advance!,
Regards

Comment: What code have you so far? What have you tried so far? (Do a step by step solution)

Comment: Do you know how to run commands and direct input and output to files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sub runCommand(strCommand)
   Dim oShell
   Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   objShell.Run strCommand, 0, TRUE
end sub
```

To run commands:

this will call the sub and run your command. The last portion of the command (> c:\temp\log.txt) will actually dump the results of the command into the log.txt file, so right after the execution you can actually open the file and parse the results, thus allowing you to make decisions on how to proceed with the script.

```
call runCommand("%COMSPEC% /c C:\Program Files\Paradigm\Paradigm-15\Services\bin\cli\PG_epos_user_list.cmd > c:\temp\log.txt")
```

Then, to get the current user:

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
Wscript.Echo "The current user is " & objNetwork.UserName
```

** for further reference on the run method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks guys!,I have this so far]:

Answer (score -2):

You can refer the below code to understand more on complex VB scripts

```
Sub Query_generate()
    Dim utilitySheet, qsheet As Worksheet
    Dim qsheet_name, rangeArray As Variant
    Dim q_range, start_range, end_range, query, qgen_col As String
    Dim i, j, k, m, n, lastRow As Long
    Dim modifiedQuery, dollar_check, cellValue As String
    Dim valuesArray(), refArray(), constant_valuesArray(), constant_refArray()
    Dim dollarSymbolFound As Boolean
    
    ' Set a reference to the "Utility" sheet
    Set utility_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("utility")
    lastRow = utility_Sheet.Cells(utility_Sheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    qsheet_name = utility_Sheet.Range("C3").Value
    Set qsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(qsheet_name)
    
    ' Check if there are values in the column
    If lastRow >= 6 Then
        ' Retrieve the values to the array
        
        n = 0
        For m = 6 To lastRow
            dollar_check = utility_Sheet.Range("C" & m).Value
            dollarSymbolFound = InStr(dollar_check, "$")
            If dollarSymbolFound Then
                ReDim Preserve constant_valuesArray(m - 6)
                ReDim Preserve constant_refArray(m - 6)
                dollar_check = Replace(dollar_check, "$", "")
                constant_valuesArray(m - 6) = utility_Sheet.Range("B" & m).Value
                constant_refArray(m - 6) = qsheet.Range(dollar_check).Value
                n = n + 1
            Else
                ReDim Preserve valuesArray(m - 6 - n)
                ReDim Preserve refArray(m - 6 - n)
                valuesArray(m - 6 - n) = utility_Sheet.Range("B" & m).Value
                refArray(m - 6 - n) = utility_Sheet.Range("C" & m).Value
            End If
            
        Next m
    Else
        MsgBox "No values found in column B."
    End If
    
    Set qsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(qsheet_name)
    q_range = utility_Sheet.Range("C4").Value
    rangeArray = Split(q_range, ":")
    
    ' Check if the rangeArray has both start and end range
    If UBound(rangeArray) = 1 Then
        ' Remove the column letter from the start_range and end_range
        start_range = Mid(rangeArray(0), 2)
        end_range = Mid(rangeArray(1), 2)
        qgen_col = Left(rangeArray(0), 1)
        
        query = qsheet.Range(rangeArray(0))
        ' Loop through the range and display the values in column
        For i = start_range To end_range
            modifiedQuery = query
            For j = LBound(valuesArray) To UBound(valuesArray)
                 modifiedQuery = Replace(modifiedQuery, valuesArray(j), qsheet.Range(refArray(j) & i).Value)
            Next j
            
            For k = LBound(constant_valuesArray) To UBound(constant_valuesArray)
                 modifiedQuery = Replace(modifiedQuery, constant_valuesArray(k), constant_refArray(k))
            Next k
            qsheet.Range(qgen_col & i).Value = modifiedQuery
        Next i
        
        
    Else
        'MsgBox "Invalid range format. Please specify a valid range."
    End If
    MsgBox "Query Generation Completed."
End Sub
```